# Filenames read from a file not getting the correct value

Tags: shell-script, character-encoding, special-characters

I have a script, which follows.

Files to be processed are stored in a file `images.txt` which is read line per line. The first `echo` command displays the file name correctly but the subsequent ImageMagick commands fail to process the image, telling that the file is not found. Why?

```
#!/bin/bash
filename="images.txt"
while read -r line
do
echo "line is $line"
# width
width="$( identify -format "%w" "$line" )" 
# height
height="$( identify -format "%h" "$line" )"
echo "$width X $height "
exit 1
if [ $width -lt 250 -a $height -lt 250 -a $width -lt $height ]
then
    echo "1"        
    convert $line -resize 250 $line

elif [ $width -lt 250 -a $height -lt 250 -a $width -gt $height ]
then
    echo "2"        
    convert $line -resize x250 $line
elif [ $width -lt 250 ]
then
    echo "3" 
    convert $line -resize 250 $line
elif [ $height -lt 250 ]
then
    echo "4"
    convert $line -resize x250 $line
else
    echo "All is Well" 
fi
done < "$filename"
```

Output:

```
line is v/347/l_ib-dfran035__62594_zoom.jpg
': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2589._zoom.jpg
```

Comment: your "line is" output is interesting for two reasons: it appears to have a newline at the end of it, *and* the filename doesn't appear to match the "no such file" filename. is that representative output?

Comment: @JeffSchaller I don't think the output has been fabricated, if that's what you mean. The filename ends with a CR (a CarriageReturn, not a NewLine) which means that, when it's displayed, the printing continues from the beginning of the line (not the next line) and overwrites the filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the error line (`': No such file...` instead of `'filename': No such file...`), the problem probably lies in your `images.txt` file, whose lines are CR-LF terminated (i.e. `images.txt` comes from the Windows world).

Because of this, your `line` variable (the file name) ends with a `CR` (carriage return) which is incorrect (no such file...). Moreover, when it gets displayed on the screen, due to the embedded control character `CR`, the printing continues from the beginning of the line and overwrites the filename.

Change the format of `images.txt` so that its lines are LF-terminated (use the `dos2unix` utility for example), or filter out the ending CR in bash.

[update] If you choose to filter out the CR in bash, you may ideally do either:

- `read -r -d $'\r' line`
- or, just after `read -r line`: `line=${line%$'\r'}`

Comment: Thanks for Reply

I have convert file using dos2unix and unix2dos but its not getting desired values.

Comment: after adding this line
line=$(echo $line |tr -d '\r')
now its working fine.

Comment: @LaxmanSinghRajpurohit `dos2unix` should do the trick (but a subsequent `unix2dos` would reverse its effect). Unless your `images.txt` file comes from a Mac?

Comment: @LaxmanSinghRajpurohit Filtering with `tr` is ok but not ideal, I have updated my answer. Since apparently my answer was right, you'd be kind to vote for it, thanks.

Comment: @LaxmanSinghRajpurohit I have edited my answer to explain what actually happens when the lines are CR-LF terminated. Hope this helps